# Using Laplace transform to solve a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse, laplace-transform, laplace-method

> Using laplace transform, find the solution $y=y(x)$ to the equation $2y'''(x)+y''(x)-y'(x)=3\sin x$ that satisfies the conditions $y(0)=1$ $y'(0)=0$ and $y''(0)=0$

I have taken a laplace transform (for now just showing the l.h.s:

$2\mathcal{L}(y''')+\mathcal{L}(y'')-\mathcal{L}(y') = -y(0)+2p\mathcal{L}(y'')+p\mathcal{L}(y')-p\mathcal{L}(y)$

$=-y'(0)-py(0)+2p^2\mathcal{L}(y')+p^2\mathcal{L}(y)-p\mathcal{L}(y)$

$=-y''(0)-py'(0)-p^2y(0)+2p3\mathcal{L}(y)+p^2\mathcal{L}(y)-p\mathcal{L}(y$

This would give me: $-p^2+(2p^3+p^2-p)\mathcal{L}(y)$

However my answer book gives: $-2p^2-p+1+(2p^3+p^2-p)\mathcal{L}(y)$

Is there an error in the book or if not could someone correct my workings please

Comment: First line. I don't know what you are doing there. Seems like you are moving up one derivative for all L terms. But then you are missing tons of terms. Re-do it slowly term of term using the [table](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf)